# Can mouseover and mouseout events be mismatched?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to track if mouse is within my HTML element or not (note: it also has child elements). The trivial solution (which I'm employing right now) is to attach to *mouseover*/*mouseout* and count them - if there are more "*mouseovers*" than "*mouseouts*", then the mouse should be within.

But I wonder - can this fail? Can either of these events be "skipped" under some (more or less bizarre) circumstances, leaving me with a mismatched count?

A few simple trials didn't yield any such situations, but then there are a lot of edge cases and I can't possibly think of them all. Has anyone ever come across such a situation?

**Clarification:** I have **not** come across such a problem. I'm wondering if such a problem is **possible** or not.

**Added:** A case just came to my mind - a *mouseover*/*mouseout* on a child element which is prevented from bubbling in its handler. Not the case for my code, but a possibility still.

Comment: An hidden element above concerned elements could give the impression that "mouseovers" or "mouseouts" don't work?

Comment: If they both don't work, that's OK. It's the case when one works and the other doesn't which worries me. If it's at all possible.

Comment: So I don't see any case sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar things happen.. driving me crazy.  I came to the assumption/conclusion that, at least in my case, it may have had something to do with event bubbling.  Are you using jquery?  It may be worth while to step though the uncompressed libraries.. if you really need the guarantee.  Otherwise, if your code is flexible enough, you could work around it..which is what I did.

Comment: yes, your edit is more clear and to the point in what I was getting at.  good to be "on the lookout" for this sort of thing..

Answer (score 0):

Bubbling is very likely the source of the problem. You get a mouseout event when the mouse moves into an inner element. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

Suggestion, use a library. They abstract cross browser differences between the mouseenter and mouseleave events which do not bubble. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

If you don't want to use a library, you need to check yourself if the mouse is within the div you're tracking before you fix the counter. If you show the code you have, it's easier to show  you how to fix it.

Comment: I have not come across a problem. I'm only wondering if this is **possible**. Currently my code works fine.